# Calling http.FileServer in an http.HandlerFunc

Tags: html, http, go, static

so I've had some trouble with this lately... Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/af1e6d922ce22597099521a4b2cfa16f

My problem: I'm trying to serve up some HTML files from a folder: `./docs/html`. My folder structure:

```
.
├── docs
│   └── html
│       ├── index.html
│       └── rest.html
└── main.go
```

You'll notice in the gist I am calling the `ServeHTTP` method on the `http.HandlerFunc` ServeDocs, which is then going through a router (`mux.Router`). The problem I'm having is for some reason the only file being served up at `localhost:8080/` is `index.html`, and when I navigate to `localhost:8080/rest.html` I get a 404.

The really odd part is that when I remove all the router code and do something like the following:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./docs/html"))
http.Handle("/", fs)

log.Println("Listening...")
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
```

Everything works as it should. Anybody know what's going on? I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I've finally given up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use `mux.Router`'s `Path` method

> ```
> r.Methods(route.Method).Name(route.Name).Handler(handler)
> r.Path(route.Pattern)
> ```

instead of `mux.Route`'s `Path` method (strikethrough'd below)

> r.Methods(route.Method)<s>.Path(route.Pattern)</s>.Name(route.Name).Handler(handler)

I am not much familiar with `gorilla/mux` so couldn't find exact reason behind this.

Comment: That is so weird lol. Just tested and it worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!